# 4 spaces for Indentation - Syntax error

Tags: python, indentation

I'm using 4 spaces for indentation, but get a Syntax error. When I use the indentation in the Text editor, works fine. The text editor creates just 1 block, that I'm unable to edit it. Are spaces not able to be used as indentation?

```
def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
    try:
            lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
            lines[line_num] = text
            out = open(file_name, 'w')
            out.writelines(lines)
            out.close()
        if not var and not var2:
            return
```

I get the syntax error on the if not var line.

Comment: Please provide the code that is throwing the error. In general, spaces are perfectly fine.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you have mixed tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 6):

If you're getting Syntax Error because of indentations it is most probably related to the fact that your code includes both *TABS* and *SPACES* as methods of indentation. Even though the code might appear to be be indented the same amount from the left, a *TAB* is a single symbol, whereas the same indentation using *SPACE*s takes 4 (in your case) symbols. Python freaks out and throws an error, because it doesn't see the rendering of code you see, it sees an inconsistent number of symbols used before the line.

To fix this, firstly substitute **all** tabs with the appropriate equivalent of spaces, and then go through your code and make sure that all the indentation in your code is valid and correct. If you're using an editor like Sublime Text then you can do this with one or two clicks, with a more primitive editor finding the *TAB*/*SPACE* difference might be much more tedious.

Hope this helps

Comment: Check the indentations. I see the line `lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()` is indented 3 times instead of 2 (1 for `def`, 1 for `try`)

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception: pass solves it. It is not needed when using indentation from a Text editor. That's weird.