# indentation:Only use indent of 4 spaces in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I open *.sol file in VSCode that already exists in the project it shows `indentation: Only use indent of 4 spaces` error even though **I'm using 4 spaces for indentation, but get a Syntax error.** Every time I have to clear that 4 space and again create 4 space for remove error.

I already have gone through the similar questions in stack overflow but didn't get approved answer. One of the related question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070917/4-spaces-for-indentation-syntax-error) .

[image: error description in image]

**Note :** I used .sol extension of vs code for compile the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

To convert existing indentation from tabs to spaces hit **`Ctrl+Shift+P`** or **`F1`** and type:

```
>Convert Indentation to Spaces
```

**Method 2:**

You can use **`solidity-solhint`** extensions in visual studio.

Click [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idrabenia.solidity-solhint).